# deep learning, memorizing the input data not learning

Tags: deep-learning

I have 1000 data sentences in Turkish like **"a esittir b arti c"**.
**The example sentence means** **"a = b + c"**. I basically want to translate mathematical Turkish sentences into math equations.

For example, i have 6 sentence data.

- sentence ("a esittir b arti c") means "a = b + c"
- sentence ("b esittir a arti d") means "b = a + d"
- sentence ("a esittir c arti d") means "a = c + d"
- sentence ("c esittir b arti b") means "c = b + b"
- sentence ("d esittir b eksi c") means "d = b - c"
- sentence ("d esittir a arti c") means "d = a + c"

After I train my neural network according to data above, **when I want the result of "d esittir a arti b", It doesn't give me "d = a + b" where it is supposed to give.
so its more like memorizing.**

My network is not big. I forced it to be small in order to make it unable to memorize. However, it didn't solve my problem.

My network **(seq2seq RNN-LSTM Encoder Decoder type)** **is working good enough on equations which have 2 3 or 4 variable** (like a = a , a = a + b , a = a + b + c). what I told you above is just **an example smaller version of my problem.**

I use *Adam* learner and *CNTK* library if it is important.

what do you suggest for me to do to be able to get the correct results?

Comment: Can you add your code and data samples to your question so it would be easier to evaluate what went wrong?